# Is dyed color inherited?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I dye a sheep and that sheep makes babies, will they violate genetics and produce offspring of the same color?  The sheep's original color?  Does it just re-roll?

Comment: It doesn't violate genetics, Dye is simply mutagenic

Comment: The discoloration could also be caused by a disease, which is passed down from parent to child :) ehehe

Answer (score 8):

If you dye a sheep, and it mates, the offspring will be one of the same colors of the parents. If you want to baby to be the same color as parents, make sure both parents are the same color.

For example:

- Blue sheep + Red sheep = Red or Blue baby sheep
- Blue sheep + Blue sheep = Guaranteed blue baby sheep

Also, if you shear a dyed sheep, the dye stays when it regrows its wool. For example, if you shear a green sheep, and then it eats grass, it will still be green.

Answer (score 4):

When you dye sheep, the offspring have the same wool color as one of the parent's current color. As stated on the [wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sheep#Breeding), the child is more likely to have the wool color of the parent that you gave wheat to first.

Answer (score -1):

I had 2 red sheep and I let them make a baby and it was purple! Some time after their next baby was blue. So it seems they don't inherit the colour from the parents.